# Automatically adding photos to donut chart points based on point name in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, photo, label, donut-chart

I'm completely new to VBA, and I'm working on a project to draw a concentric donut chart showing a number of different brands. I'm trying to automatically attach the brand logos to the outer ring of the donut chart. My idea is to have one loop that first names each point of the series with the brand name, and a second loop that refers to a file location that contains the  logos, finds corresponding logo, and pastes that logo into the point.

I found some previous questions/answers about how to name points on a pie chart, but I can't seem to get any of them to work on my donut chart. I managed to copy a single named picture from the file location into a single chart point using

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Brand").Points(1).Format.Fill.UserPicture ("C:...\Abrand.JPG")
```

but this isn't very sophisticated and I don't know how to scale it up to automatically paste any logo into a corresponding point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and as I'm very new if you could annotate what you've done so I can learn that would be very much appreciated too!

Answer (score 0):

If you can map your label values to your logo names you can do something like this:

```
Dim BrandChart As Chart
Set BrandChart = ActiveChart

Dim Brand
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
For Each Brand In BrandChart.SeriesCollection("Brand").XValues
    i = i + 1
    BrandChart.SeriesCollection("Brand").Points(i).Format.Fill.UserPicture "c:\...\" & Brand & ".jpg"
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! Just so I understand, what does the " & ... & " around Brand in the file address mean? I'm trying to learn as much as I can =)

Comment: It is the string concatenation operator. It joins strings together. The expected result is a file path starting with a folder and then the brand name, ended with .jpg. This relies on the logo files having the same name as the brands in your list.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work? I checked and everything else works, the points are labelled correctly, but the concatenation operator is causing an error message. Currently the file names of the photos are just the brand names so this should work no?

Comment: Ah now it works! I'm not sure why it works but it does. Thanks so much for your help Sam! Have a lovely weekend too =)